# Backbone.js in an offline application

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am using Titanium to build a desktop app using web technologies. I decided to use Backbone.js as my mvc. The problem is the application runs not on a server. This is my Backbone model and collection:

```
     window.Student = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function(){
            this.bind("save", this.value_change);
        },
        value_change: function(){
            alert("Student model saved for : " + this.attributes.first_name);
        },

        urlRoot : http://localhost:8080/student/,
    });

    window.Students = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Student,
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/students/',
    });
```

and try fetching the values from the server using

```
var students = new Students  
students.fetch()
```

I get this error:

```
message: "'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$.ajax')"
```

I am assuming this has to do with the url part. It is not able to fetch the values from the server. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your answers. The problem laid in loading jquery after backbone. I loaded jquery first and it worked out fine. Thanks to parshap from the irc of #documentcloud.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is backbone saves models on a server. It does this by sending ajax requests to your server. What you want to do is overwrite the persistence mechanism

Use [backbone.localStorage](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage) to save state in localStorage rather then a database

Answer (score 0):

`collection.fetch()` will fire a `reset` event on the collection, and not a `save` event. Save is a Model method to execute a POST request to your server, when you want to persist your instance model on your server.

You should try this instead :

```
window.Student = Backbone.Model.extend({
});


window.Students = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Student,
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/students/',

    initialize: function(){
        this.bind("reset", this.value_change);
    },
    value_change: function(){
        alert("Students fetched ");
    },
});

var students = new Students();
students.fetch();
```

I'm not sure what you mean when you say

> The problem is the application runs not on a server

But if your javascript does not run on the same domain as your server, you may have some cross domain javascript issues...  Here is post with an exemple using Ruby on Rails : http://www.tsheffler.com/blog/?p=428

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/Ask11/backbone.offline

Allows your Backbone.js app to work offline